# How to make editable of specific <TD> of a Table onclick of another td

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with some rows,here I need to make editable of the column which contains yes/no  onclick of edit,again when I click outside it should be non editable.Here is the code below.

### html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="test"><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>

        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
    alert('hi');
    $(this).parent().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the code whatever I tried but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.parent()` only goes up one level in the DOM, and in your case that would be the `<td>` parent of the link. You want `.closest('tr')` which will continue up the DOM until matches.

```js
$(".edit").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('input').blur(function(){
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="test"><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>

        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just nit-picking but I believe the OP asked that the input be disabled whenever you click outside of the input. For your solution, it only disables it if you click on the input first before clicking anywhere else. Still upvoted though as this is a correct answer.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio valid point but the handler for `$(this).prop('disabled', true)` could be extended to trigger based on a click on the body or another element.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
          $('table .edit').click(function(event) {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
          });
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td class="test"><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>

        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled value="Yes"></td>
        <td><a class="edit" href="#">edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```